# Не сохраняется заданная скрипту в Editor ссылка на объект в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor

Вкратце:
У меня есть **скрипт чекпоинта**(1) и **скрипт, сохраняющий определённые значения**(2). Из 1 поступают координаты респавна в 2. В чекпоинте в инспекторе  я сослался на 2, но при запуске ссылка слетает, и в графе ссылки на 2 написано None *(Внизу фото)*.

Теперь поподробнее:
вот код 1:

```
public class checkpointScr : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool opened = false;
    //data это то, что нам нужно
    public dataScript data;
    public BoxCollider2D mycollider;
    public PolygonCollider2D playercollider;
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public Sprite newSprite;
    public Light Light1;
    public Light Light2;
    AudioSource mySounding;
    public AudioClip mySound;
    void Start()
    {
        data = GetComponent<dataScript>();
        mySounding = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Light1.intensity = 0;
        Light2.intensity = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (mycollider.IsTouching(playercollider) && opened == false)
        {
            Light1.intensity = 1;
            Light2.intensity = 1;
            opened = true;
            mySounding.PlayOneShot(mySound, 0.9f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = newSprite;
            //здесь скрипт передаёт координаты
            data.x = gameObject.transform.position.x;
            data.y = gameObject.transform.position.y - 1.6f;
            data.z = gameObject.transform.position.z;
        }
    }

}
```

Вот код 2:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class dataScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //тут совсем пусто
    public float x = -3.01f, y = -1.73f, z = 0;
}
```

То, что я использовал, чтобы устранить проблему:

- Называл public dataScript по другому
- Перезагружал Unity
- Использовал копию чекпоинта
- Переподключал скрипт к чекпоинту
- Использовал скрипт на другом объекте (результат тот же)

Но зато я могу без всяких проблем используя те же строчки выполнять это в другом скрипте. Так-же я могу после запуска заново подключать 2 к скрипту и всё спокойно работает.

До запуска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В действительности надо было просто убрать строчку «data = GetComponent dataScript ;”. И всё.

Answer (score 0):

Так у тебя на старте ищется объект с данным параметром, т.е. он не статичен, полагаю в этом причина. Он у тебя инициализируется после запуска сцены.

Comment: И как это исправить?